# Read from non-CSV file using JMeter

Tags: jmeter

I'm looking for an option to read a non-CSV file using one of the JMeter functions. The file i'm using has extension of .csr. This file has a binary array format which would be converted to json format using a Java code. Jmeter has to pass the data from this file to the Java class.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is using [__FileToString()](https://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-functions-part-iii) function to read the file into a [JMeter Variable](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) for reusing where required.

Another option is: given jar file(s) which can decode that .csr binary file into JSON are in JMeter CLASSPATH you can do it directly in JMeter using [JSR223 Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) which allows executing arbitrary code in variety of supported languages (groovy is recommended for maximum performance)